# How add imoticon socket.io using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

I am currently working on a chat using **socket.io**, i got a problem when i try to add some smilers and parse to the content "div" how can you pass the string value from the input text to a split of object to parse the content div displaying message + icon "

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bf2">
<!-- ::before -->

</div>
<form action="">
  <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
</form>
```

**Server side:**

```
    socket.on('filter message', function(msg){
          user.id = socket.id;
            user.name("user_" + socket.id);
            user.country("France");
            user.age = "20";
            user.msg = msg;
            users.push(user);
            var i = msg.split(/\s*(<p[^>]*\/>)/g);

                  console.log(i);

          io.emit('chat message', {"msg":i, "user":user.get()});
    });
```

**Client side:**

```
    socket.on('chat message', function(data){

                  var user_id = data.user.id;
                  console.log(data);
                  var text_message = (data.msg);


                  if(typeof text_message === 'string')
                    addMessage(user_id, text_message);
                  if(typeof text_message === 'object'){
                    var merge_message = "";
                    for(var i in text_message){

                      if(text_message[i] !== ""){
                        if(parseInt(i) === 1){
                            merge_message += text_message[i];
                          }else{
                            merge_message += "<p>" + text_message[i] + "</p>";
                          }
                      }
                    }

                    setContent(merge_message);

     };
```

Comment: any html to show us?

Comment: yes sorry i will add now ty ;)

Comment: what should the different job of addMessage and setContent?

Comment: AddMessage just append to the div#bf2 as childNode and setContent transform a string to multi-object html.

Comment: So i guest you need to post setContent because this is where you got an error?